# ShapeableImageView has black overlay

Tags: android, kotlin, android-xml

I'm using the new ShapeableImageView to make a circular image, but the overlay is showing up as black.  How can I make it transparent?  This is what it looks like:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/CircleImageView"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

```
<style name="CircleImageView">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: ref this link: https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/446c63ea2aed81aafc0bdec1488e27c9, if you still facing any issue, mention what version are you using.

Comment: Same issue here with 1.2.0 and 1.2.1

Comment: It turned out it's just a preview issue, if you run the app you shouldn't see the black background

Comment: Somehow i still see this during fragment transitions. any clues how to get rid?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just like @Matteo Innnocenti mentioned at the comments, It is just a preview issue when you run the app you should not see the black background

For more people to see I post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the background colour directly, try to set it this way

```
// instead of this:
// iconImage.setBackgroundResource(item.colorResId)

// use this as workaround
val shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(RectShape()).apply {
        colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(iconImage.context, item.colorResId), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }
iconImage.setBackgroundCompat(shapeDrawable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add
`android:padding="1dp"` 
or
`app:contentPadding="1dp"`
on the ShapeableImageView 
and check the overlay.

It worked for me, based on 
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1329

Answer (score 0):

Removing android:hardwareAccelerated="false" from manifest solves the problem. See discussion [here](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/446c63ea2aed81aafc0bdec1488e27c9)